# If the associative law doesn't hold, can we define $a^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, associativity

I am reading "Higher Algebra" by A. Kurosh.

The following sentence is in this book:

> Analogously, the associative law of addition leads to the
> concept of a *multiple*, $na$, of the element $a$ by a positive
> integral coefficient $n$

If the associative law doesn't hold, then we cannot define $a^n$.
Is it really true?

---

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbaAy.png

Comment: Rings are usually defined to be associative ... if you want an example of a non-associative operation where this does not hold, consider the positive integers ${1, 2, 3, \ldots}$ and the exponentiation operator. $3^{3^3} = 3^{27}$, but $(3^3)^3 = 3^9$, and $3^{27} \neq 3^9$.

Comment: @Joppy exponentiation is not distributive

Comment: Perhaps unsatisfying, the free nonassociative algebra on 2 generators (over your favorite field) should work

Comment: @Joppy Thank you very much.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: Somos, Thank you very much for your edit.

Comment: @KentaS Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: The cross product of vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ is not associative. The NOR operator in logic is communative but not associative.

Comment: @bof Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: If the operation is nonassociative (see dupes for examples) then there can be more than one way to associate $3\cdot a = a+a+a,\,$ viz. $\,(a+a)+a\,$ or $\,a+(a+a)\,$ and ditto for $\,n\cdot a\,$ for larger $n$. So any bracketless notation is not well-defined when the operation is not associative absent any convention, e.g. define it to be left-associated e.g. $(((a+a)+a)+a)\ \ $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we define a non-associative binary operation $\circ$ on $\Bbb R$.
$x\circ y:=x-y$
trying to figure out the third (or higher) power causes problems.
$1\circ (1\circ 1)=1-(1-1)=1$
$(1\circ 1)\circ 1=(1-1)-1=-1$
$(\Bbb R,\circ)$ is a non-associative magma, so it is not a semigroup. it is not an example of a non-associative ring or algebra though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).